# Construct binary tree from prefix order expression

Tags: binary-tree, prefix

How should we construct the binary tree of the following "**prefix**" order expression?

( -  *  /  8  +  5  1   4   +  3  -  5  /  18  6 )

Is there any rule to follow for drawing the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudocode is like this:

```
function MakeBinaryTree(expr):
  element = next element in expr
  if element is a number:
    return a leaf node of that number
  else: // element is an operator
    left = MakeBinaryTree(expr)
    right = MakeBinaryTree(expr)
    return a binary tree with subtrees left and right and with operator element
```

Here `expr` keeps an internal pointer pointing to where the next element is.

Comment: I'm a little confuse. first I make a tree(8-> left, 6->right, / ->root). how can I connect (1) to the tree(i.e by what operator). Could you please show me by drawing the tree.

Comment: for the expression you gave, it would be
(- (* (/ 8 (+ 5 1)) 4) (+ 3 (- 5 (/ 18 6))))